# Search Nuget packages programmatically by partial name match

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

I've already figured out how to search and download Nuget packages using [this guide](https://daveaglick.com/posts/exploring-the-nuget-v3-libraries-part-1). But I can only search by exact package name, while I want to search packages by partial name match like I do in Visual studio package manager. However, I didn't found any workarounds to achieve this functionality.

The only concept I have in mind for now is loading whole list of packages in gallery page by page and somehow look for names matching. But it appears to be too much time-consuming approach.

I'll appreciate any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Well, required functionality already exist, it can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/api/search-query-service-resource)